# Disable crash dialog box in C

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cygwin

I would like to disable (in a VS2010 C program) the crash dialog window which pops up on screen when a GPF occurred (You know the **xxx.exe as stopped working**)

I tried on win2008 and win7:

```
 - SetErrorMode(SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX)|SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
 - try/catch (with SEH, but some parts of the code aren't wrapped in)
 - SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()
```

Nothing works... still with this damned window

Do I forget something ?

The only thing which is working is to modify the "DontShowUI" key in register base
(**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting**)
but it's just not clean, and I would prefer a "coding" solution (and I cannot change the register into my code !)

Do you have an idea ? (except fixing the program itself to avoid the GPF of course :)

Thanks...

note : Interesting, under Cygwin the crash dialog doesn't appear !

Comment: `SetErrorMode(SetErrorMode(`? Really?

Comment: Your comment doesn't help, and please read : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/27/198410.aspx. Another (better) idea ? Thanks

Comment: How about disabling it for your application using WerAddExcludedApplication() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Or if you only want to disable the UI but leave the WER functionality you can try WerGetFlags()/WerSetFlags() to turn off the WER_FAULT_REPORTING_ALWAYS_SHOW_UI flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to disable the crash box is to remove whatever code is causing your program to crash. This box will never appear for a correct program.

**Edit:** As for what's actually wrong with your call to `SetErrorMode`, it should be:

```
SetErrorMode(SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX)
    |SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS|SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
```

or similar. I think you misread the blog article you cited in the comments.

Comment: It's still very possible (although not necessarily) that the crash is due to you breaking the contract for that library's interfaces...

Comment: Being that you misused `SetErrorMode`, I wouldn't be so sure about your use of the DLL...