# C++ Disable Buffer Overrun Box

Tags: c++, crash, minidump

My problem is that during the app crash it's popping up  a buffer overrun message, I am using minidumps which sets an unhandled exception filter, which, is enough to make the program simply crash and close instead of popping up messages.

I have tested the program dereferencing a NULL pointer as soon as the filter is applied, and it worked on the server machine (where the program is set to run), although even with the filter, the application on release mode and no debug defined, will still pop-up the message.

This problem is very serious, because we have another application to automatically restart it every time it crashes, which isn't happening because on the crash a message box is shown instead of the program closing, it is a server, and it should have no downtime, also due to the message box the .dmp file isn't being created.

Comment: Have you tried [Disable crash dialog box in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454596/disable-crash-dialog-box-in-c)

Comment: disable the overrun message box

Comment: @ViniciusHorta I didn't understand your last comment. Does the post suggested by WhozCraig answer the problem? If yes, we could close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @jogojapan, nono, it is an answer for Mats question, he asks what is my problem, I tell him!

Comment: Ok. Actually, he asked what your _question_ was. Indeed there is no explicit question in your post. But anyway, what do you say about WhozCraig's link?